# What is the name of this Superman enemy?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, character-identification

I read the comic in 1980s but not in English so it could be before the 80s in English.

This enemy is an evil spirit that kills people and eventually kills the host (yes, it requires a host) and when the host dies, this spirit moves to another host. This evil was recorded since prehistoric times, when the punishment for this spirit was by throwing stones at it. If my memory is not wrong, it was also the one who influenced Cain to kill Abel.

I forgot why it wanted to take over and try to kill Superman. One way that was tried to get rid of it was by means of blood transfusions, with many volunteers giving blood to Superman, but the attempt failed. In the end, Superman tricked it by going to outer space where there is no life, and this spirit cannot move to another host.

I tried to search this in list of Superman enemies from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Superman_enemies), but I cannot find the right enemy.

Comment: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_403?

Comment: Yes, you're right, @Valorum , wow you're fast

Comment: @Valorum Post an answer?

Comment: @Spencer - Apologies. I would have done it sooner but I was on my mobile and copying pictures over is like pulling teeth.

Comment: There was a Denzel Washington movie from the 90's called 'Fallen' that had a very similar premise, I wonder if they took inspiration from the Superman story?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The villain in question is a ***Zohtt***.

Its sole appearance was in *[Action Comics Vol 1 403](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_403)* - *"Attack of the Micro-Murderer"* where it uses its powers to infect Superman's bloodstream.

[image]

Superman gets a super-transfusion with the blood from hundreds of Metropolites, including Lois Lane.

[image]

Comment: "Blood pressure terrific enough to rip apart a 100ft dam" - that's some pretty tough gauze tape they've got on his IV then

Comment: @Whelkaholism - Hush now. Your sensible thinking and logic have no place in the world of Superman.